# to get max(date) and the max date should not be the current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to this field. pls help me out. I have a table along with a date column, I want to get record based on latest date. so I have used `max(date)`, but then I realized the `max(date)` should not be today's date. any help in sql server will be appreciated.

```
declare @comp1 bigint
set @comp1=(select isnull((select sum(completed_count) as a from table1 where JOBID=580 and status<>'I' and targetdate=(select max(targetdate) from table1 where status<>'I' and id=580)),0) )
declare @bal1 bigint
set @bal1=(select isnull((select TotalVol from table2 where TargetDt=(select max(TargetDt) from table2 where status<>'I' and id=580) and Id=580 and Status<>'I'),0))
declare @pend1 bigint
set @pend1=(select isnull((select count(id) as c from table3  where status='p' and MOD_PROJ_ID=171 and id=580 and 
UPDATED_DT=(select max(UPDATED_DT) from table3 where status='p' and id=580) group by id),0))
select @bal1-@comp1+@pend1 as answer
```

sorry I new to stackoverflow as well. help please

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit what you mean by "the max(date) should not be today's date" ? Do you want the latest date older than the current day?

Comment: can you post sample data and expect output

Comment: yes @Raul.. that's right

Comment: in my table, I may have records for today's date...but I want @bal1-@comp1+@pend1 calculation for the latest date older than the current date..@chanom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read in your comment, you need to extend your where clause by

```
UPDATED_DT < CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS date))
```

when selecting the max date:

```
UPDATED_DT=(select max(UPDATED_DT) from table3 where status='p' and id=580 AND UPDATED_DT < CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS date)) group by id),0))
```

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept the answer as the correct one if I was able help.